# Notify other activity of a preference changed

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to have the main activity notified of a change in preferences in the PreferenceActivity but the onSharedPreferenceChanged  is not firing when I change the preference.

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()
    {   
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
        {
            Log.d("Dict", "PreferenceChanged: " + key);
        }
    });
```

Comment: When are you executing this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is (because it's a common mistake) that you are registering the listener in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()`. That will prevent the listener from firing. If that's what's happening, changing your code to register during `onCreate()` and unregister during `onDestroy()` will fix the problem.

Comment: Should I really remove the listener? I'm using an anonymous class.

Comment: @piotr - When you don't remove a listener, it gets called even after the activity has been destroyed. This can happen, for instance, when the user simply rotates the device. Calling a listener for a destroyed activity can cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: @TedHopp You're totally right, I was using `onPause()` and `onResume()`. Docs are recommending that: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Listening

Comment: @RafaelOliveira - Yeah, I don't know why the docs are recommending that phase of the lifecycle. I guess it has its uses in detecting a preference change caused by another thread, but I've always been more interested in being notified of changes by (say) a preferences activity that pushes my activity to the background (and hence pauses it). Unregistering in onPause completely defeats that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code
Find the what Preference current value change according to his key

public class SharedPreferences implements
        OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
        android.content.SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, defValue);
    sharedPreferences.getFloat(key,defValue);
    sharedPreferences.getInt(key, defValue);
    sharedPreferences.getString(key, defValue);
    sharedPreferences.getString(key, defValue);
}
```

}

Comment: Isn't that basically what OP is already doing? The problem is that `onSharedPreferenceChanged` isn't being called.